# Is "I am study at school" grammatical?

Tags: verbs, progressive-aspect

Can we use third statement or not?

1. > I study at school "correct"
2. > I am studying at school "correct"
3. > I am study at school.

Comment: Both the first two are fine, but in practice people would usually use #2 (Present Continuous with ***am*** used as an "auxiliary, helper" verb), because it draws attention to the fact that studying is what you're *currently* doing. Note that ***studying*** there is a 100% ***verb*** usage. In other contexts it could be a noun (gerund) meaning ***the act of** studying*, which may be what gave you the mistaken idea that you could use another noun form *(study)* in #3 (you can't - that one is simply ungrammatical).

Comment: #3 is incorrect because the progressive form requires a present participle (*studying*) and not an infinitive or conjugated form.

Comment: But **I am to study at school** is absolutely correct but has a very different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you shouldn't use it because it's ungrammatical.**

It's a common mistake non-native speakers make.

> *I am try to . . .
>     *You are make me . . .
>     <sub>* means it's ungrammatical</sub>

They're not using the correct inflectional form because their native tongue usually permits similar structures, which a lot of Asian languages do, to my information.

If you search around a bit, you'd find a lot of good posts on progressive vs. "simple" form of the present tense. [This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20065/14111) is one such example.

There are also certain verbs that tend not to appear in progressive constructions, called stative verbs. [Here's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/33556/14111) instructions on how to know one when you see one.

Comment: wait, so this is wrong?                                                                         
She is busy.
We are at work.
My colleagues are free.
It is difficult.
Your house is big.
These problems are serious.
I am ready.

Comment: @Gilani those are different. "study" is a verb, but "ready", "busy" etc. are adjectives. The function those adjectives play in those sentences is called 'predicative complement', and the main verb, and the only verb of those structures is the 'be' verb.